# How to use jQuery in HtmlUnit executeJavaScript(query) argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, htmlunit

I extensively use the "executeJavaScript(String queryText)" method of the HtmlPage class (HTMLUnit). It works nice, but it does not recognize jQuery or $ symbols inside queryText. I assume I need either initialize the internal jQuery support or include jQuery library. Does anybody know how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have script tag that downloads jquery script before you execute that statement. Best place for it is within the head element of the page. Another possibility is that you have another third-party script redefining `$` (it's a common thing): then you can try using `jQuery` in place of `$` within your query-text.

Comment: Hi Hari, Thank you for prompt answer. But I see a problem. If I understood correctly, you suggest to put something like <script src="jQuery lib.js" > in my query. May be just before the text.  It is not working. I think HtmlUnit effectively places the query, that is supposed to execute inside some script tag. This means that my jQuery script tag will be placed inside another script tag that is not allowed. I need a way to place my script tag on top of  other script tags that are already in the page. But I do not know how.

Comment: Thank you again, you gave me an Idea. I will append a script tag to the head tag via a function. It will look something  like this: var scriptTag = document.createElement("SCRIPT"); scriptTag.addAttribute("src","jQuery.js"); var head = document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD"); head.appendChild(script);On Tuesday when I will have access to my work computer, I will try to implement this idea. I will post the result. However, even if this will work, it is a work around. There should be a standard way to include the jQuery support.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting `< script src="jQuery lib.js" >`. First, you have to make sure jQuery exists on the page (here's one way: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp). Then, in your query-test, if  `$(".myclass")` doesn't work, try `jQuery(".myclass")`.

Comment: I do not have problems with pages containing jQuery scripts. I assume HtmlUnit handle them fine. But suppose a page does not contain jQuery library.  But I still want to use jQuery notation in the script that I am going to execute in the page context via "page.executeJavascript". This would greatly simplify for me writing the script. I see only two possibilities. Either HtmlUnil can somehow inject jQuery library into the page if it does not have its own, or I have to check and insert it myself if necessary. The question is how???

Answer (score 0):

```
String jQueryInjector = 'eval(
  function loadJQuery(){
   var newJQueryLib = document.createElement("script");           
   newJQueryLib.type = "text/javascript";
   newJQueryLib.src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1
                                                       /jquery.min.js";
   (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||document
     .getElementsByTagName("body")[0])
     .appendChild(newJQueryLib););
  loadJQuery();';
ScriptResult sr = page.executeJavaScript(jQueryInjector);
```

Comment: 1.jQueryInjector  is  one string that is used as a parameter for  executeJavaScript. I omitted some quotes and + signs to make it more readable. jQueryInjector is defined once and executeJavaScript(jQueryInjector) runs for every new page, if it is expected not to contain a jQuery library.

Comment: 2. This is not the best way to inject jQuery. It uses eval and loads jQuery lib from the Internet. In future I am going to use direct DOM manipulation and the local library. But as a first cut it works fine for me. I hope it will be useful to somebody.